# Django1.8 'app' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

My error:

```
    <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'app:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter}}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
    </form>
```

I want to know why it's wrong here.
This is the official website of the document is written

This `detail.html`:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'app:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}    </label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Now I know the problems is in `detail.html`, my main urls and my app called myapp URLCONF and `views.py`

`views.py`:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

My `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.Index,name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$',views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking here. Do you get an error? Unexpected behaviour? Something else? Please see: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespacing is used when you include another url config inside your root `urls.py`. The example in the tutorial works because they have `include('polls.urls')` [in tutorial 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view), and then [in tutorial 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) they have set `app_name = 'polls'` in `polls/urls.py` and changed the url tag to `{% 'polls:vote' question.id %}`.

In your case, all your url patterns are in the root config, so you should remove the namespace from your url tag.

```
{% url 'vote' question.id %}
```

Comment: Thank you, you'vebeen most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[My Project picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sBN2.png)

I added a new urls.py

this code，mydjango/urls.py

---

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

app/urls.py

---

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```